# (H.W) What is the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (1/\sqrt{(4n^2 - k^2)})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Honestly I don't know where to begin with. I though of using tricks like $1/(ab) = (1/a - 1/b) \times1/(b-a)$ but the square root term is bothering me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard about riemann's series ? Compare it to an integral.

Comment: Use $a=\sqrt {2n+k}$ and $b=\sqrt {2n-k}$. The square root shouldn't be much of a problem. If anything, I think it helps simplify in the $\frac 1{b-a}$ part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{4-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}}
$$
Hence

> $$
> \frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{4-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\frac{\pi}{6}
> $$

**Reminder :**

For $f : \left[a,b\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\left(a,b\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ ( $a<b$ ) then
$$
\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right) \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow} \int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)\text{d}x
$$
To fully understand this equality, notice that you are approaching the area of the function defined between $x=a$ and $x=b$ with rectangulars areas. The more $n$ grows, the more you split $\left[a,b\right]$ into thin rectangulars that better approaches this area as the image http://www.mathly.fr/images/sriemann.png shows.